# Permutations vs. Combinations: when to divide

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm using the Princeton Review online prep course for the GRE and am having trouble understanding their explanation for the following question:

" Two-player tennis teams are selected from the 6 boys and 6 girls in a tennis class.

Quantity A: The total number of possible teams consisting of two girls
Quantity B: The total number of possible teams consisting of one boy and one girl.

A Quantity A is greater
B Quantity B is greater
C The two quantities are equal
D The relationship cannot be determined from the information given "

For Quantity A, it would be 6 * 5 / 2! since order does not matter. In their explanation, they say, "The team of Suzette and Tina is not different from the team of Tina and Suzette," which makes sense. However, they say Quantity B is just 6 * 6 - NOT divided by anything because "the choices are from different sources." But this doesn't make sense to me since the team of Suzette and Bob is not different from Bob and Suzette...

Can anyone elaborate on why being from different sources means I don't divide?

Comment: Consider that there is only one boy and one girl. How many mixed teams are possible?

Comment: In A the choices are “first girl” (6 possible choices) and “second girl” (5 remaining choices), but order does not matter. In B, the choices are “a boy” (6 possible choices) and “a girl” (6 possible choices), nothing about order.

Comment: @Engineer trying math’s technique is an IMPORTANT problem solving technique for your toolkit, especially when taking tests: trying a much simpler version of ‘similar’ problem, to test your understanding/proposed solution. For example, if there’s girl1, girl2, boy1, and boy2; compare the number of all girl teams possible to the number of mixed teams possible (You do not actually need to compute the numbers, just COMPARE them!)

Comment: For both A and B, picture a $6 x 6$ matrix where you make choices inside the matrix. In B, each of the $36$ boxes is a different pair of people. In A, there are two differences: first the diagonal elements don't count since they don't include two different people, and second, the symmetrically located non-diagonal points contain the same pair of people, so you have to divide ($6*5=30$) by $2$, and that is because in A, the row and column sets are the same, while in B they are disjoint ("different sources").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretend that order did matter. Maybe the team has a captain and a lieutenant.

In A, there are 6 choices for the captain (all 6 girls), then 5 choices for the lieutenant (all 6 girls except for the captain). Total is $6 \cdot 5 = 30$.

In B, there are 6 choices for the captain (all 6 girls), then 6 choices for the lieutenant (all 6 boys). But wait - the captain could have been a boy! So we also have to account for 6 choices for the captain (all 6 boys), then 6 choices for the lieutenant (all 6 girls). Total is $2 \cdot (6 \cdot 6) = 72$.

---

But order doesn't matter. So for both A and B, we divide the result by $2!$.